# Can any account play Heroes once it's been downloaded?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I've got more than one battle.net account, but only one has Heroes of the Storm closed beta access. Now that I've downloaded the game, can I play with either account, or will it not work with my alt?

Answer (score 4):

It will only work with whichever account has the closed beta access. You won't be able to play with your alt account.

Answer (score 4):

The game will show up on both battle.net clients, but you will be able to play with the one which has the access. On other account, you'll get authentication error.